# Download Tor, but when when I open it says its damaged and should be moved to trash?

Tags: error

What's that about? I had a perfectly fine functioning version of Tor before but it tells me I have to update and whadayaknow, all of sudden I have no access whatsoever. I'm pissed, to be frank. I run a Mac. The .dmg downloads and passes to the applications folder but when I try to open it it says it's damaged and that it should get moved to trash. What!? Help

Comment: Did you update by clicking on the Tor Button inside the Tor Browser? Where are you downloading the .dmg file from?

Answer (score 0):

Download https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/7.0.11/TorBrowser-7.0.11-osx64_en-US.dmg

Next make sure your Mac is up to date. "open the App Store and click on the updates tab and install any updates"

Create a new folder on the desktop and name it.

Then open the DMG you downloaded and drag TorBrowser into the new folder you created on the Desktop.

Open TorBrowser "The one that is in the folder you created." and it should work